# API call setvalue for is_primary does not make other values 'not primary'

Tags: api, addresses

When using the CiviCRM API to make a field primary, other fields in the set do not have the 'is_primary' flag removed. This results in multiple 'primary' fields.

Eg: Address A is primary. The setvalue API call is used to set is_primary on Address B. Now addresses A and B both have 'is_primary'.

Is this the desired behaviour?

I can see that setvalue is intended to be quite a low level function, so you might not expect it to unset is_primary on other fields in the set. But if this is the desired behaviour we should probably [document it](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Using+the+API).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of problems with the setvalue api. This is a good example of why everyone should stop using it.

The plan is to deprecate setvalue soon and remove it in a future version. See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16643

Comment: Sounds good, I've updated the documentation page.